# LiveView Disconnected from Event Server

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Getting [LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable @ 192.168.7.151:8324 error while running Appcelerator in the phone. It is working fine in simulator.

Here is the error, [ERROR] : ReferenceError: OS_MOBILEWEB is not defined [ERROR] : File: /alloy.js [ERROR] : Line: undefined [ERROR] : SourceId: undefined [ERROR] : Backtrace: [ERROR] : undefined [ERROR] : TypeError: Alloy.createController is not a function [ERROR] : File: app.js [ERROR] : Line: undefined [ERROR] : SourceId: undefined [ERROR] : Backtrace: [ERROR] : undefined [ERROR] : [LiveView] Disconnected from Event Server

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest liveview version (`npm i -g liveview`) if you use the CLI or make sure you are not behind a firewall / VPN. If you are, you can configure it in your `ti config` settings.